# More elegant way of find a range of repeating elements

Tags: python

I have this problem.

let `l` be a list containing only 0's and 1's, find all tuples that represents the start and end of a repeating sequence of 1's.
example

```py
l=[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]
```

answer:

> [(0,2),(5,8),(9,10)]

i solved the problem with the following code, but i think it is pretty messy, i would like to know if there is a cleaner way to solve this problem (maybe using map/reduce ?)

```py
from collections import deque
def find_range(l):
    pairs=deque((i,i+1) for i,e in enumerate(l) if e==1)
    ans=[]
    p=[0,0]
    while(len(pairs)>1):
        act=pairs.popleft()
        nex=pairs[0]
        if p==[0,0]:
            p=list(act)
        if act[1]==nex[0]:
            p[1]=nex[1]
        else:
            ans.append(tuple(p))
            p=[0,0]
    if(len(pairs)==1):
        if p==[0,0]:
            ans.append(pairs.pop())
        else:
            ans.append((p[0],pairs.pop()[1]))
    return ans
```

Comment: Why would it return `(9, 10)`? Is a single `1` still considered a repeating sequence in this case?

Comment: @JamesMchugh Yes, it would be a sequence of length 1.

Comment: Interesting problem, mostly because all the answers seem a bit unsatisfactory. Don't get me wrong they're all good answers but by Python's standards none of them are exactly readable. Your effort might be described as 'old fashioned' I suppose: lots of loops and quite verbose. The two answers so far make use of more modern features of Python and are very clever, but not sure any of them feel elegant. I was heading for something similar to the zip/enumerate option but stopped when it seemed like it was getting too messy. Sometimes even Python doesn't seem to offer the clarity that we'd like.

Comment: @SimonN Yes, i fully agree with you, do you think it's better to change the question to "more modern" or "more readable" or "less messy" ?

Comment: @llpinokio See my answer, although not very elegant, I broke it up into steps and explained the logic so it should be clear what each step does.

Comment: @SimonN I disagree. I think the solution that uses `itertools.groupby` by @RomanPerekhrest is very elegant. It is pretty readable as well, but I think its readability suffered slightly from two things: 1) Many Python users may not understand what `groupby` does, 2) the use of `enumerate` on the first argument of `groupby`. The first issue is solved easily by referring to the docs that are linked to in the answer, and the second is solved by creating a variable that holds the indices like so `indices = range(len(lst))`. That changes the code slightly, but not enough to require a new answer.

Comment: Please see RomanPerekhrest's updated solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) *magic*:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
indices, res = range(len(lst)), []
for k, group in groupby(indices, key=lambda i: lst[i]):
    if k == 1:
        group = list(group)
        sl = group[0], group[-1] + 1
        res.append(sl)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[(0, 2), (5, 8), (9, 10)]
```

---

Or with a more ***efficient*** generator function:

```
def get_ones_coords(lst):
    indices = range(len(lst))
    for k, group in groupby(indices, key=lambda i: lst[i]):
        if k == 1:
            group = list(group)
            yield group[0], group[-1] + 1

lst = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
print(list(get_ones_coords(lst)))   # [(0, 2), (5, 8), (9, 10)]
```

---

As a short **bonus**, here's alternative `numpy` approach, though sophisticated, based on discrete difference between consecutive numbers ([`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)) and extracting indices of *non-zero* items ([`numpy.faltnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)):

```
In [137]: lst = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]                                                                                        

In [138]: arr = np.array(lst)                                                                                                

In [139]: np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0, arr, 0]) != 0).reshape(-1, 2)                                                      
Out[139]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 5,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

Comment: Great solutions, and thank you for introducing me to `itertools.groupby`. However,  I think the readability of your generator function might be made slightly better if you created a separate `indices` variable instead of using `enumerate(lst)`. Other than that, +1 from me.

Comment: I am aware, I just believe that it slightly impacts the readability of your code as stated in the comments of the question. I think [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-mchugh/3be2cfd0cfc1360c19544c763998314e) is slightly more readable, but of course beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @JamesMchugh, Ok, let's apply your suggestion. Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 2):

#### Code:

```
a = [[l.index(1)]]
[l[i] and len(a[-1])==2 and a.append([i]) or l[i] or len(a[-1])==1 and a[-1].append(i) for i in range(len(l))]
```

#### Output:

> [[0, 2], [5, 8], [9]]

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
l=[1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]   

indices = [ind for ind, elem in enumerate(l) if elem == 1]
diff = [0]+[x - indices[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(indices)][1:]
change_ind = [0]+[i for i, change in enumerate(diff) if change > 1]+[len(indices)]
split_indices = [tuple(indices[i:j]) for i,j in zip(change_ind,change_ind[1:])]
proper_tuples = [(tup[0], tup[-1]) if len(tup)>2 else tup for tup in split_indices]

print(proper_tuples)
```

## Logic:

1. `indices` is the list of indices where l elements = 1 => `[0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9]`
2. `diff` calculates the difference between the indices found above and appends a 0 at the start to keep their lengths the same => `[0, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2]`
3. `change_ind` indicates the locations where a split needs to happen which corresponds to where `diff` is greater than 1. Also append the first index and last index for later use or else you will only have the middle tuple => `[0, 2, 5, 6]`
4. `split_indices` creates tuples based on the range indicated in consecutive elements in `change_ind` (using zip which creates the combination of ranges) => `[(0, 1), (5, 6, 7), (9,)]`
5. Lastly, `proper_tuples` loops through the tuples create in `split_indices` and insures that if their length is greater than 2, then only consider the first and last elements, otherwise keep as is => `[(0, 1), (5, 7), (9,)]`

## Output:

```
[(0, 1), (5, 7), (9,)]
```

## Final Comments:

Although this does not match what OP suggested in the original question:

> [(0,2),(5,8),(9,10)]

It does make more logical sense and seems to follow what OP indicated in the comments.

For example, at the start of `l` there are two ones - so the tuple should be `(0, 1)` not `(0, 2)` to match the proposed `(start, end)` notation.

Likewise at the end there is only a single one - so the tuple corresponding to this is `(9,)` not `(9, 10)`